# Any help with decoding this cypher?

Tags: cipher

Can anyone help me decode this cypher? I have absolutely no clue what the key is. All I’ve been told is that it’s a substitution cypher and looking for words with double letters, like ‘mass’ and ‘kill’, may help. (My subject in school is mass killings). Even any tips would be great! Thanks :)[image]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: What school offers "mass killings" as a subject?

Comment: I’m a psychology/criminology student at university. From what I can tell my module is mostly based around mass shootings so maybe that will help?

Comment: Double letter words- the double s and the double l

Comment: FWIW, a Unicode approximation of the image:

```
UBU/+⬤M+Q⅃
FF/UBBUORQ
D⌖YB+UƎB⅃U
QQ□Ω⊥UZ+D/
```

Comment: @dan04 Some of those letters are flipped though, like looking from the other side of a window.

Comment: @JLee: I know, but I couldn't find suitable Unicode characters for backwards D or Q.

Comment: Really reminds me of Zodiac's ciphers, with those symbols and backward letters.

Comment: @JLee: I'm sure that's deliberate.

Comment: FWIW, the repeated symbols in the ciphertext are:

* U (7 times)
* B (5 times)
* +, Q (4 times each)
* / (3 times)
* D, F, ⅃ (2 times each)

Doubled symbols are BB, FF, and QQ; used once each.

And repeated sequences of distinct symbols are BU and UB, used twice each.

Comment: I confess I have trouble believing that a university has a _module on mass killings_ which involves _solving cryptographic puzzles to "claim your prize".

Answer (score 0):

## Partial answer

Assuming that “words with double letters, like ‘mass’ and ‘kill’” are not just random examples, then the plaintext could be

> I like the mass killing m???leilaimm???i?e?k

but I'm struggling with the second half of it.

Comment: “I like the mass killing module I claim my prize ok” I think - thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: Please do not answer questions which are off-topic per our [attribution policy](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide); that policy is in place to prevent cheating and plagiarism.